# automatic convert matlab code (with image processing toolbox inside) to c for integration the c code in c# dot net

Tags: matlab

my friend write great function that do image processing in matlab (with image processing toolbox),
there is a way to auto generate this matlab code to c code (source code) that i can wrap it in dll that .net can load???

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
class PlatformInvokeTest
{
    [DllImport("imp.dll")]
    public static extern int puts(string c);
    [DllImport("imp2.dll")]
    internal static extern int _flushall();

    public static void Main() 
    {
        puts("Test");
        _flushall();
    }
}
```

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MATLAB Compiler can do that. Use

```
mcc -X MyFunction.m
```

This will generate the '.dll', the C source code, its header file and a MEX wrapper on C.
Read [this](http://technologyinterface.nmsu.edu/5_1/5_1f/5_1f.html) carefully to know other options.